# value from javascript-controller to be used as global variable in apex controller

Tags: apex, javascript-controller

i want to pass a string from my javascript-controller to apex controller so that it can be used as a global variable(string) in Apex controller
below is the code

{.....user is selecting a group name from the list of groups and im passing the group id of the selected group to apex controller so that i can use the group id to do the further operations on the server side such as connect, disconnect, send message, get all the users from the group etc....}

i want to use the group id in more than one meethod in my apex controller

```
controller.js

connect:function(component, event, helper){
        var selectedItem = component.get("v.selectedvalue");
        var action = component.get("c.getGroupId");
        // want to use selectedItem as a global variable (string) in apex controller
        //action.setParams({postmsg1:selectedItem});
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for more information on the type of detail we're looking for.

Comment: user is selecting a group name from the list of groups and im passing the group id of the selected group to apex controller so that i can use the group id to do the further operations on the server side such as connect, disconnect, send message, get all the users from the group etc

Answer (score 1):

Each transaction is a clean slate as far as global/static variables are concerned. You can't store "state" on the server or in between requests. This has a distinct advantage that Lightning can perform much better than Visualforce (up to 10x faster, in fact). To be absolutely crystal clear, you cannot store data in global variables, as they will not persist across transactions. You must pass in the value(s) you want to use for each separate transaction/Apex call.

Comment: is it possible to store the group Id any how in javascript,aura or apex? so that once user select the group he can perform further tasks on the group

Comment: @Tejas If all these other tasks like "connect", "send message" etc. need to happen on a button click, you should be passing the "groupId" in each of those calls to apex (you can retrieve it from your component.get("")).
As sfdcfox alluded to, there's a shift in how to solve problems in Lightning vs Visualforce. There's no concept of a saved state between requests. 
Whilst this is LWC, you might find some ways of how this is done in some examples in  https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc

Comment: @Tejas You store the Group Id in JavaScript, either as attributes (Aura) or class members (LWC). You would then pass this in as a parameter for each method you write so you can do further operations with the Group.

Comment: i figured it out that it can be done with  two methods for this..1)by storing groupId in javascript (as @sfdcfox suggested)....2)by storing the group id in a record in salesforce database and acess it using select query....